# Maze generator library

Tags: open-source, library, java, game-development

Randomly generated game worlds are currently very popular. Can anyone recommend an open-source Java library for tile-based maze (bird's-eye view) creation?

Features I have in mind:

**Basic**

- two exits, that are always connected
- adjustable x / y dimension
- output: two dimensional array
- cycles

**Advanced**

- rooms
- wide corridors
- empty space
- multiple number of exits
- additional output: solution path

**Pro**

- teleport fields
- a key / door concept
- multi-layer spreaded maze

*Update:
The book [Mazes for programmers](https://pragprog.com/book/jbmaze/mazes-for-programmers) helped me. The code is in Ruby.*

Comment: This is not really a library but the information that is shown on this page should help in the creation of your maps. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: Some more links which may be of interest: [Wilson's Algorithm](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/11357811) and [Rooms and Mazes: A Procedural Dungeon Generator](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2014/12/21/rooms-and-mazes). In particular, I find the latter to be a great read.

Comment: I asked a [maze question on PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49068/leonhard-loves-labyrinths) and it has a nice JavaScript solution (regarding the outcome, I can't judge about the source).

Comment: I know this post is relatively ancient, but you might want to check out http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/daedalus.htm - I've used Daedalus several times for maze creation and never had issues with it.  Might be more work than you want to put into it, though, to get it to work in whatever your project is.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a maze generation library written in Java 7+, and would be willing to discuss its use.

I also found an example of a simple maze generation algorithm [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation), that should help put you on the path to writing your own maze generator if you don't find something that suits your purposes.

Comment: And, is the maze generation library available now?

Comment: The algorithm isn't anywhere near where I want it to be, it mainly just generates a maze at a given size, but is not a "perfect" maze generation. Just added my email to my profile. I'd be happy to discuss it in more detail with anyone that would like to know more.

Comment: Create a grid.  Treat it like a graph; every neighbor is connected to 4 other neighbors except at the edges and corner.   Pick a random cell,  Build a spanning tree with this cell as the starting place; when expanding the spanning tree, choose random edges.  Place walls on every graph edge not used by the spanning tree.  Done.